Compare 3 CASE expressions for an overall value
I have a Postgres database with a table named servers containing these columns:

compliance status
operating system version
reference ID  - if a server is not compliant or the os is not the latest version.

Some of the compliance values aren't as black and white as 'PASS' or 'FAIL'. So I first generate com_passfail with just 'PASS' / 'FAIL' using a CASE expression.
Some of the os versions aren't black and white either. So I generate os_passfail with just 'PASS' / 'FAIL'.
Finally, I generate overall_status like this:
If com_passfail or os_passfail is 'PASS' then a new column overall_status is 'PASS'.
If com_passfail or os_passfail is 'FAIL' and ref_id is NOT NULL then overall_status is 'PASS'.
If com_passfail or os_passfail is 'FAIL' and ref_id is NULL then overall_status is 'FAIL'.
Sample rows for table servers:



server
compliance
os
ref_id




SERVR1
PASS
OK



SERVR2
GOOD
BAD



SERVR3
OK
VALID



SERVR4
FAIL
PASS



SERVR5
BAD
ACCEPT
TICKET1


SERVR6
NOGOOD
FAIL
TICKET2



Expected Output:



server
compliance
os
ref_id
com_passfail
os_passfail
overall_status




SERVR1
PASS
OK

PASS
PASS
PASS


SERVR2
GOOD
BAD

PASS
FAIL
FAIL


SERVR3
OK
VALID

PASS
PASS
PASS


SERVR4
FAIL
PASS

FAIL
PASS
FAIL


SERVR5
BAD
ACCEPT
TICKET1
FAIL
PASS
PASS


SERVR6
NOGOOD
FAIL
TICKET2
FAIL
FAIL
PASS



I tried CASE expressions to implement above rules:
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN compliance = 'PASS' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN compliance = 'GOOD' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN compliance = 'OK' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN compliance = 'FAIL' THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN compliance = 'BAD' THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN compliance = 'NOGOOD' THEN 'FAIL'
END AS com_passfail,
CASE
WHEN os = 'PASS' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN os = 'OK' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN os = 'VALID' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN os = 'ACCEPT' THEN 'PASS'
WHEN os = 'FAIL' THEN 'FAIL'
WHEN os = 'BAD' THEN 'FAIL'
END AS os_passfail
FROM servers

I created a view using the above query and another view selecting everything from the query and then doing a comparison between com_passfail and os_passfail to determine the overall_status value.
Is there a way to generate the result table above in a single query?

You never provided any feedback on your similar previous question.

Hi @TimBiegeleisen - my apologies.  Still trying to get used to how to properly edit/post questions here as I am new to using this site.  I posted an updated (new) version of my question here with more detail.  Thanks again for your intial response!  My new/updated question here should hopefully clarify what i was trying to ask in my initial question.  Apologies if i didnt format my “expected” table properly in this question!

Be precise. "If com_passfail or os_passfail is 'PASS' then a new column overall_status is 'PASS'" - No, your expected result shows that is not the case, for then the second row would pass, not fail. You want "If com_passfail and os_passfail is 'PASS' then ...".

Unless there are undeclared corner cases, simplify with Boolean logic instead of CASE expressions.
And one plain subquery (even that optional) instead of multiple views:
SELECT *, com_pass AND os_pass OR ref_id IS NOT NULL AS overall_pass
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , compliance IN ('GOOD', 'OK', 'PASS') AS com_pass
        , os = ANY ('{PASS,OK,VALID,ACCEPT}') AS os_pass
   FROM   servers
   ) sub;

Demonstrating equivalent IN and ANY expressions. Either is good. See:

IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL

com_pass AND os_pass OR ref_id IS NOT NULL works without parentheses because of operator precedence.
If you need text output:
SELECT *, CASE WHEN com_pass AND os_pass OR ref_id IS NOT NULL
               THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS overall_pass
FROM  (...) sub;  -- like above

fiddle
Produces your expected result precisely.
Aside: use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers in Postgres if at all possible. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


Yep. I'd make this (com_pass AND os_pass) OR ref_id. I know that AND has precedence over OR, but I think that parentheses help readability here.

@ThorstenKettner: Redundant parentheses to clarify won't hurt. I kept it short, since this is on the topic of reducing overly verbose code.

@Charlieface Why would an array constructor be better than a constant?

@ErwinBrandstetter - thank you so much! your solution worked perfectly for what I was looking to achieve! Much appreciated!

@Charlieface: If anything, the constant is "better" (unless context forces you to construct the array dynamically). Typically, it makes no real difference. An array constructor has to be executed, while the constant is processed via basic I/O routines. In some contexts, you can't pass an array constructor from clients. In some contexts, you may need an explicit type cast, but that applies to either variant.
